# Clojure: Expand a var in let binding dynamic value var

Tags: clojure

following this question [Clojure: Expand a var in let binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449649/clojure-expand-a-var-in-let-binding) and solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/20450289/1074389 provided by @amalloy 
I was wondering if i could dynamically pass values to the let form vars

So starting with this code proposed by @ammlloy ...

```
(defmacro with-common [& body]
 `(let ~'[x 10, y 20]
 ~@body))

(with-common (+ x y))
```

I would need this extension of the functionality ...

```
(defmacro with-common [x-val y-val & body]
 `(let ~'[x x-val, y y-val]
 ~@body))

(with-common 2 3 (+ x y)) ;; => 5
```

Thanks in advance!
Juan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if i could dynamically pass values to the let form vars

Yes, this approach seems to do what you want:

```
(defmacro with-common [x-val y-val & body]
  (let [bindings ['x x-val 'y y-val]]
    `(let ~bindings ~@body)))

(with-common 2 3 (+ x y))
;=> 5
(macroexpand '(with-common 2 3 (+ x y)))
;=> (let* [x 2 y 3] (+ x y))
```